# Why do I have to download the 1.12.2 update every time I open the launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

It's starting to irritate me that I have to download the 1.12.2 update every time I go to open up Minecraft. I don't know why it is, but it's only this update, and only this computer that I'm using. The computer worked fine with every other update before this, but now isn't. Why do I have to do this? Is there a solution?

Comment: Sounds like computer troubleshooting which is generally considered off topic.  Even if it were not, you would have to provide details about the computer and the installation.  I have heard similar complaints that ended up being Windows 10 computers which had the User folder write protected.  If you are using Windows 10, you might look into that possibility.

Comment: @IronAnvil I have Windows 7, and I already looked at that.

Comment: One thing you could try is creating a new launch option that uses a different game directory.  Temporarily create a directory that is not in possibly protected space.  See if the problem persists.

Comment: Does it actually take long to download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided what you say is true.

Completely uninstall Minecraft
used a registry cleaner like ccleaner to make sure the computer is clean.

also 1.12.2 exclusively runs on java 8. Make sure you have updated to Java 8 latest version.

Get a decent Minecraft launcher like the TwitchApp.

Enjoy.